# How do aneroid gauges and electronic gauges measure pressure?

Tags: pressure

Aneroid Gauge: How does this fluid distort a metallic element, and how is the pressure of the fluid derived from the distortion ?

Electronic Gauge: How does a fluid generate a pressure dependent electrical signal that can be converted into a pressure reading?

Comment: What specifically is giving you trouble?  Do you need to know more about how pressure works, or are you just confused about some specific mechanisms?

Comment: I wanted to understand what components these gauges consist of and how they work to determine the pressure of a fluid. Niels Nielsen provided an answer that explained these mechanisms. I made some edits to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an aneroid gauge contains a hollow, flat metal can with a flexible top and bottom. it is sealed airtight. when the external air pressure is greater than the internal pressure in the can, its ends bulge inward and a set of very tiny gears convert that bulging into the rotation of a needle against a calibrated dial. when the internal air pressure is greater than the external pressure, the top and bottom bulge outward and the needle moves in the opposite direction.

Electronic pressure gauges contain a flexible membrane on which a serpentine metal trace called a *strain gauge*  has been deposited. The membrane forms the top of a sealed capsule containing air. when the membrane bulges in or out as in the above example, the resistance of the metal trace changes very slightly in proportion to the amount of bulge and a sensitive electronic circuit converts the resistance change into a pressure reading.

In some electronic pressure gauges, the membrane is a thin slab of silicon on which the strain gauge trace has been photolithographically defined. In this case the processing electronics are right on the same silicon chip that contains the thin membrane. It is common for that chip to also contain a temperature sensor which compensates the gauge for changes in ambient temperature, so it maintains proper calibration across a wide range of temperatures automatically.